# External CPU design

Tags: signal, computers, cpu, processor, motherboard

Apologies if this is a dumb question. I don't have any training in electrical engineering, so I can't gauge for myself how ridiculous this sounds.

Would it be possible to modify a commercial CPU so that it does not have to be directly in contact with the motherboard?

That is, with the right conducting medium, would it be possible to significantly increase the distance between a CPU and the motherboard? And if so, is there some theoretical or practical maximum distance?

Comment: With the right conducting medium (some kind of 2D zebra foam, I have never sean such stuff, but it might exist) you might be able to achieve a disance of a few mm, maybe even a few cm. 10's of cm's will be completely impossible for current PC-level CPUs. Things will be different if you take stone-age processors (for instance a 8088, like in te oriiginal IBM PC) into consideration.

Comment: It might be possible, but good luck doing this with recent CPUs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but with the socketed processors you could build an extender that lets you move the CPU a short distance off the motherboard.

You can't move it a *long* way off the motherboard because the increased signal propagation time becomes signifigant. A 1GHz signal has a cycle time of 1ns; in that time a signal can travel a maximum of 30cm, limited by the speed of light. Lengthening this will eventually interfere with normal operation somehow.

Comment: Yes, but even with good board layout processors generally run their off-package memory bus many times more slowly than their core already.  Only the closest level of cache can actually keep up.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the conventional meaning of terms such as "motherboard", but in effective functional terms then yes.

For example, you could take a smartphone, and connect it to a simple desktop computer via wifi or bluetooth.  Have a program actually run on the phone's CPU, but use the desktop display, keyboard, and mouse for user interface.

Once you've done that, it would actually be legitimate to start calling the simple CPU on the original "motherboard" an "I/O processor" and that in the wirelessly coupled device doing the actual application processing the "CPU" - because those are the roles that these devices would actually be playing in your computational assembly.

And yes, you could use RAM on the main board as an auxiliary storage, though a fairly slow one.  That starts to raise a major issue why such designs are limited to particular purposes: if you substantially isolate the processing unit from the rest of the system, then the limited connection to the rest of the system can become a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But I was curious as to whether it would be possible for a computer to use a CPU remotely. In that example, the thin client still needs its own CPU to do basic IO operations.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Give me a pair of wires for connection and I can do it all with state machines in an FPGA rather than a stored-program "processor".  However, having I/O co-processors in real computers is an idea that goes back to the dawn of programmable machines.  And from the 80's it wasn't uncommon to have the *same* chip that could be used as *the* CPU in a small system be used as an I/O processor in a slightly more complex one.  The IBM PC from the start has had I/O processors - modern PC's have many.  This idea would not be conceptually different, only different in degree.